# How i get count lines in terminal

Tags: terminal

I need a total of lines in terminal output

Like `cat lista_de_compras.txt`:

```
arroz
feijão
leite
```

I want to get 3

Answer (score 4):

Use **grep**:

`grep -c ^ lista_de_compras.txt`

The output will be **3**

---

or use the cat with the **wc**

`cat lista_de_compras.txt | wc -l`

The output will be **3**

---

Or Use only the **wc**:

`wc -l lista_de_compras.txt` (suggested)

The output will be **3**

Answer (score 2):

A way to do it is as follows:

```
cat lista_de_compras.txt | wc -l
```

See: https://ss64.com/bash/wc.html